# How to turn a string into an element call

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

Given I have:

```
b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto 'google.com'
string = "div(:id => 'main')"
```

The `string` is supplied by a user.

Is there a way to use the specified string, which describes how to locate an element, to locate the element in the browser? In other words, how can I execute the string as if the following was written:

```
b.div(:id => 'main')
```

I have tried with `b.send(string)` but this only works for `string = url`:

```
b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto 'google.com'
string = "div(:id => 'main')"
b.send(string)
#=> "https://www.google.com"
```

When locating an element, like `string  = "div(:id =>'main')"`, I get an undefined method error:

```
b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto 'google.com'
string = "div(:id => 'main')"
b.send(string)
#=> undefined method `div(:id =>'main')' for #
```

Comment: I am not sure why there are so many close votes (currently 4). I have tried to edit the question to make the examples more clear and hopefully prevent the question from being closed.

Comment: @JustinKo I think your edit made my answer totally invalid... :) waiting to delete my answer also..

Comment: @michael please unmark my answer, so that I can delete my one.. Accept the answer of *Justin Ko*. *Justin* is one of an *Watir* Hero..

Comment: @ArupRakshit, I do not think your answer is made invalid by the edits. It does still answer the question - ie fixes the exception that was seen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are getting Watir commands as strings, I assume the commands could get more complicated. For example:

```
# Locating based on a partial match (ie regexp)
string = "div(:id => /main/)"

# A locator value with non-word characters
string = "link(:href => 'some/url')"    

# Locating nested elements
string = "div(:id => 'main').span(:class => 'text')"
```

Manually parsing these types of strings is more complicated than just scanning the string for words. For example, in the regexp example, just scanning for words would end up giving you the locator `{"id"=>"main", :tag_name=>"div"}`. Notice that the id is now looking for an exact match of "main", which is not what the string wanted.

Therefore, I think you should use `instance_eval`, which would eliminate the need for manual parsing:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

b=Watir::Browser.new
b.goto 'https://www.google.com'

# Original string
string = "div(:id =>'main')"
p b.instance_eval(string)
#=> #<Watir::Div:0x61221438 located=false selector={:id=>"main", :tag_name=>"div"}>

# Locating based on a partial match (ie regexp)
string = "div(:id => /main/)"
#=> #<Watir::Div:0x42afd800 located=false selector={:id=>/main/, :tag_name=>"div"}>

# A locator value with non-word characters
string = "link(:href => 'some/url')"    
p b.instance_eval(string)
#=> #<Watir::Anchor:0x2b625f26 located=false selector={:href=>"some/url", :tag_name=>"a"}>

# Locating nested elements
string = "div(:id => 'main').span(:class => 'text')"
p b.instance_eval(string)
#=> #<Watir::Span:0x..fb341cd56 located=false selector={:class=>"text", :tag_name=>"span"}>
```

Comment: `BasicObject#instance_eval` is very good option too go... I forgot it that time..

Comment: This really do simplifies things :)
Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Try this as below :

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

b=Watir::Browser.new
b.goto 'https://www.google.com'

string = "div(:id =>'main')"
meth,*selector_arr = string.scan(/\w+/)
# => ["div", "id", "main"]
selector_hsh = Hash[*selector_arr]
p b.send(meth,selector_hsh)
# >> #<Watir::Div:0x5b248f1c located=false selector={"id"=>"main", :tag_name=>"div"}>
```

Comment: This works ofcourse as long as it passed not as a string.
`string = ":div,:id =>'main'" ; b.send(string)` doesnt work.

Comment: @MichaelR There can be several options... But that's the way to go..with your current string just do `string.split(',')`.

Comment: @ArupRakshit , Ive copy-paste your code  and its not working :-\ 

`[53] pry(main)> string = "div(:id =>'main')"
=> "div(:id =>'main')"
[54] pry(main)> string.split(/\(|\)/)
=> ["div", ":id =>'main'"]
[55] pry(main)> b.send(*string)
NoMethodError: undefined method 'div(:id =>'main')' for #<Watir::Browser:0x007fd4031e5328>
from (pry):29:in '__pry__''`

Comment: Now its working :) Thank you !

Now if i could only figure out why i got the "-1" 
Wa my question wrong/bad ?

Comment: While this is a good idea for solving the example in the question, the manual parsing can be error prone. For example, this will not correctly handle regexp - "div(:id => /main/)".